# DNS Server not responding (Interworx)

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-server

I have a dedicated server with interworx installed, and in its control panel I have created a site account for the dedicated ip Address 173.234.60.106 under the domain name fluffyspikes.com. Additionally I have set up the DNS Server in the control panel to use ns1.fluffyspikes.com which is a name server I registered through my domain registrar.

The dilemma is that it's not finding the site. Here's what I see as a dns lookup at http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3awww.fluffyspikes.com%2f#

[DNS Report Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxZjY.png)

We recently had everything set up, but my partner accidentally erased the entire server so we're stuck setting this up again, and I thought that all I would have to do is re-add the nameserver like so:

Screenshot of Setup link: 173.234.60.106/screen1.png

From my understanding when I type in fluffyspikes.com in the url, it should look up nameserver for where that domain is pointing to our DNS Server, go there, and our DNS Server should tell it to point to the the web hosting account in our control panel. If I am missing a crucial step let me know.

I don't know where throughout the process it is failing. Let me know if this is not enough information, as I am a web developer, not a server engineer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im taking the assumption that you only have one interworx server and do not have it setup in any sort of cluster configuration.

From the screenshot that you have provided there seems to be an IP address that is not currently registered on the system.

After doing a whois on your domain I noticed the following

```
Domain servers in listed order:
NS1.FLUFFYSPIKES.COM   173.234.60.106
NS2.FLUFFYSPIKES.COM   173.234.60.107
```

Notice how 173.234.60.107 is listed as NS2 however not on the screenshot on the server (see your attached screenshot)

As an interworx user myself I can tell you that you will need to go to you interworx control panel Select **Server** --> **IP Management** --> **System IPs** and add your 173.234.60.107 IP to the system

Afterwards go to **System Services** --> **DNS Server** --> **Zones** and select your fluffyspikes.com domain. Make sure that the records are going to the right IP address (assuming its 173.234.60.106)

You should see A record for fluffyspikes.com being pointed to 173.234.60.106

Let me know if this solves your issue!

Good luck!

Comment: I added 107 to the System IPs as it wasn't there before, but the zone file was already updated correctly, here's a screen shot 173.234.60.106/screen2.png

Comment: One other thing, I noticed the IP Management section isn't showing the right root folder for any of the IP's except mvmdesign.org 173.234.60.106/screen3.png I'm thinking it may have something to do with the etc/httpd/conf.d folder and the virtual hosts not pointing to where they should. Like I said I don't know much about this, so I can only guess

Comment: Ok, in your nodeworx panel, go to **Siteworx** -> **Accounts** Click on Edit for domain FLUFFYSPIKES.COM and make sure the IP address is the right IP address and not a 192.168.1.x address. Let me know

Comment: Here's what it looks like 173.234.60.106/screen4.png

Comment: From what I'm reading, there's no found authority for this ip address, which makes me think my DNS is failing to connect to the outside world. looking at this site http://www.process.com/techsupport/multinet/787/44.html maybe the boot file contains the wrong IP address, yet sadly I have no idea where/what these files are.

Comment: We will get this resolved! Go to your DNS zones again and add an NS record for FLUFFYSPIKES.COM. Host should be FLUFFYSPIKES.COM  and the record Data should be NS1.FLUFFYSPIKES.COM and then add another NS record for NS2.FLUFFYSPIKES.COM . Interworx Should have added these records automatically when you had created the account.

Comment: Glad to be able to help!

Comment: I may be asking for too much now, but I have another domain that is on a local ip of the server 192.168.1.10 and when I do a nslookup of mvmdesign.org it shows THAT ip address, even though I've changed the domains A record in it's zone to be the 173.234.60.106 address, because i know that 192 is local and doesn't mean anything to computers not on that server

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7615/discussion-between-nick-m-and-marius-miliunas)